# Curl Ответ сервера 0

Tags: php, xml, curl

такой вопрос. Есть база с номерами на 400 тыс товаров. необходимо брать номер и отправлять xml запрос curl. С сервера поставщиков приходит ответ в xml, он парсится и база обновляет значение этого номера. Поставщики поставили лимит запросов 50 тыс. в день. После запуска скрипта он отрабатывает штук 200 и ответ сервера становится 0.
Сам скрипт:

```
    while($myrow = $stmt->fetch()) { // цикл по базе товаров
        $post_data  = "<GET_Input></GET_Input>"; // запрос к поставщику с номером товара
        $url = "blabla.ru"; // ссылка на поставщика
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(бла бла)); // заголовки для аутентификации
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $error = curl_errno($ch);
        $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        echo "answer server - $status_code\r\n";
        curl_close ($ch);
        if($status_code == 200) {
            // если все вернул, то рассовываем по таблице
        }
    }
```

Comment: "`...становиться...`" -.-

Comment: спасибо, исправила. А по теме есть что-то?